# How to position the element using absolute position?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I am trying to create a responsive design for my app.

I have a big background image and it will show the full size when user has large screen and only show partial if user uses small screen.

I want to place few elements on my app with absolute position but the problem is I can't lock their top and left value because the screen size changes.

I have something like

css

```
#background{
    background: url('BG.jpg') no-repeat top center fixed;
    width: 1900px;
    height: 1200px; 
}

#element{
   position: fixed;
   z-index: 5;
   top: 50%;   //looks fine in 1900 x 1200 screen but position is off on 1200 x 1000
   left:70%; //looks fine in 1900 x 1200 screen but position is off on 1200 x 1000
}
```

html

```
<div id='background'></div>
<img id='element' src='test.jpg' />
```

How do I keep the position of the element on the same spot when user has small screen? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Either use @media queries in css or you would have to use js to do some calculations.

Comment: I have tried @media queries but no luck. Would you please provide some example of calculation?

Comment: you can use `background-size:cover` to make a background shrink/stretch to the containers bounds. note it isnt supported on older browsers

Comment: So on smaller screens the background is still 1900 x 1200? Also, you want the element fixed or absolute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `position: absolute`, you need to make sure that it has a parent with a `position` attribute other than the default (which is `static`).  If there is no such parent, the document is the effective parent.  For your example, I would advise making the img#element a child of div#background like so

```
<div id='background'>
    <img id='element' src='test.jpg' />
</div>
```

and then adding `position:relative;` to the #background css style

```
#background{
    background: url('BG.jpg') no-repeat top center fixed;
    width: 1900px;
    height: 1200px;
    position: relative;
}
```

The reason `relative` is used, is because it doesn't take the element out of the document flow (like `fixed` or `absolute` would) and as long as you don't specify a `top`, `left`, 'bottom', or `right` attribute to the parent (`#background` in the case), it will stay in the same location as it would with default positioning.

### Edit:

I don't think this will work out of the box for you.  You need to figure out how to make the image's width dynamic as well.  You can either give it a % based width or use media queries.

### Edit 2:

Ia also just noticed you have `position:fixed` for `img#element`.  Change that to `position:absolute`.  that will make it so that it is positioned relative to the `position:relative` parent rather than the window.

Answer (score 0):

Consider making a javascript function that calculates the screen width. After that add margin-left to #background equal to ( screen width / -2 ). Make #background width & height - 100%